# Adding multiple <script>s to a specific page in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I'm trying to add two scripts to a specific page in a gatsby.js app.

The page is `/apply`, and the second script depends on the first (the first script must be loaded before the second).

Of course this is straightforward on a traditional site as the scripts would be loaded synchronously in order. But in react-helmet, the scripts are loaded asynchronously so my second script errors (its trying to call a function in the first before the first is loaded).

I've taken a hook from https://usehooks.com/useScript/ and am trying to get things working.

If I inspect the page source after load, both scripts are present but I still get errors in the console (as if script2 is trying to run before script1).

`myPage.js`

```
const Apply = () => {
  const  scriptLoaded  = useScript("https://myscripturl/script1.js");

   if(scriptLoaded !== "ready"){
    return <>Not loaded</>
   }

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        {scriptLoaded === "ready" &&
          <script src="https://myscripturl/script2.js"></script>
        }
      </Helmet>
      <!-- The rest of the page -->
    </>
  )  
}
```

`useScript.js`

```
// taken from https://usehooks.com/useScript/
function useScript(src) {
  // Keep track of script status ("idle", "loading", "ready", "error")
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(src ? "loading" : "idle");
  useEffect(
    () => {
      // Allow falsy src value if waiting on other data needed for
      // constructing the script URL passed to this hook.
      if (!src) {
        setStatus("idle");
        return;
      }
      // Fetch existing script element by src
      // It may have been added by another intance of this hook
      let script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${src}"]`);
      if (!script) {
        // Create script
        script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = src;
        script.async = true;
        script.setAttribute("data-status", "loading");
        // Add script to document body
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        // Store status in attribute on script
        // This can be read by other instances of this hook
        const setAttributeFromEvent = (event) => {
          script.setAttribute(
            "data-status",
            event.type === "load" ? "ready" : "error"
          );
        };
        script.addEventListener("load", setAttributeFromEvent);
        script.addEventListener("error", setAttributeFromEvent);
      } else {
        // Grab existing script status from attribute and set to state.
        setStatus(script.getAttribute("data-status"));
      }
      // Script event handler to update status in state
      // Note: Even if the script already exists we still need to add
      // event handlers to update the state for *this* hook instance.
      const setStateFromEvent = (event) => {
        setStatus(event.type === "load" ? "ready" : "error");
      };
      // Add event listeners
      script.addEventListener("load", setStateFromEvent);
      script.addEventListener("error", setStateFromEvent);
      // Remove event listeners on cleanup
      return () => {
        if (script) {
          script.removeEventListener("load", setStateFromEvent);
          script.removeEventListener("error", setStateFromEvent);
        }
      };
    },
    [src] // Only re-run effect if script src changes
  );
```

If I place both scripts in the index.html in `/public`, the code works without issue. But of course it runs on every route in the app which is no good. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gatsby's Script API: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/

It also has a section about loading script dependently: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-script/#loading-scripts-dependently

So your code could be:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Script } from "gatsby"

function Apply() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://myscripturl/script1.js" onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)} />
      {loaded && <Script src="https://myscripturl/script2.js" />}
    </>
  )
}

export default Apply
```